# Make python code run faster

Tags: python, performance, optimization

I have the following code:

```
for stepi in range(0, nsteps): #number of steps (each step contains a number of frames)
    stepName = odb.steps.values()[stepi].name #step name
    for framei in range(0, len(odb.steps[stepName].frames)): #loop over the frames of stepi
        for v in odb.steps[stepName].frames[framei].fieldOutputs['UT'].values: #for each framei get the displacement (UT) results for each node
            for line in nodes: #nodes is a list with data of nodes (nodeID, x coordinate, y coordinate and z coordinate)
                nodeID, x, y, z = line
                if int(nodeID)==int(v.nodeLabel): #if nodeID in nodes = nodeID in results
                    if float(x)==float(coordXF) and float(y)==float(coordYF): #if x=predifined value X and y=predifined value Y
                        #Criteria 1: Find maximum displacement for x=X and y=Y
                        if abs(v.data[0]) >uFmax: #maximum UX
                            uFmax=abs(v.data[0])
                            tuFmax='U1'
                            stepuFmax=stepi
                            nodeuFmax=v.nodeLabel
                            incuFmax=framei
                        if abs(v.data[1]) >uFmax: #maximum UY
                            uFmax=abs(v.data[1])
                            tuFmax='U2'
                            stepuFmax=stepi
                            nodeuFmax=v.nodeLabel
                            incuFmax=framei
                        if abs(v.data[2]) >uFmax: #maximum UZ
                            uFmax=abs(v.data[2])
                            tuFmax='U3'
                            stepuFmax=stepi
                            nodeuFmax=v.nodeLabel 
                            incuFmax=framei
                        #Criteria 2: Find maximum  UX, UY, UZ displacement for x=X and y=Y    
                        if abs(v.data[0]) >u1Fmax: #maximum UX
                            u1Fmax=abs(v.data[0])
                            stepu1Fmax=stepi
                            nodeu1Fmax=v.nodeLabel
                            incu1Fmax=framei
                        if abs(v.data[1]) >u2Fmax: #maximum UY
                            u2Fmax=abs(v.data[1])
                            stepu2Fmax=stepi
                            nodeu2Fmax=v.nodeLabel
                            incu2Fmax=framei
                        if abs(v.data[2]) >u3Fmax: #maximum UZ
                            u3Fmax=abs(v.data[2])
                            stepu3Fmax=stepi
                            nodeu3Fmax=v.nodeLabel 
                            incu3Fmax=framei 
            #Criteria 3: Find maximum  U displacement            
            if abs(v.data[0]) >umax: #maximum UX
                umax=abs(v.data[0])
                tu='U1'
                stepumax=stepi
                nodeumax=v.nodeLabel
                incumax=framei
            if abs(v.data[1]) >umax: #maximum UY
                umax=abs(v.data[1])
                tu='U2'
                stepumax=stepi
                nodeumax=v.nodeLabel
                incumax=framei
            if abs(v.data[2]) >umax: #maximum UZ
                umax=abs(v.data[2])
                tu='U3'
                stepumax=stepi
                nodeumax=v.nodeLabel 
                incumax=framei
            #Criteria 4: Find maximum  UX, UY, UZ displacement    
            if abs(v.data[0]) >u1max: #maximum UX
                u1max=abs(v.data[0])
                stepu1max=stepi
                nodeu1max=v.nodeLabel
                incu1max=framei
            if abs(v.data[1]) >u2max: #maximum UY
                u2max=abs(v.data[1])
                stepu2max=stepi
                nodeu2max=v.nodeLabel
                incu2max=framei
            if abs(v.data[2]) >u3max: #maximum UZ
                u3max=abs(v.data[2])
                stepu3max=stepi
                nodeu3max=v.nodeLabel 
                incu3max=framei
```

This code accesses a results database file created by a numerical analysis program and retrieves the maximum displacement of the deformed shape of a civil engineering structure, given certain different criteria. 
The problem is that this code takes about 10 min to run. The number os steps `nsteps` may be 1 to 4, the number of frames (`framei`) may be more than 2000 and the number of `nodes` may be more than 10000.
Is there a way to make this code faster?

Comment: have you evaluated the complexity of your algorithm ?

Comment: It looks like for each iteration of `for v in odb...` you'll only actually do any processing under one iteration of `for line in nodes:`.  Can you change your data structure up front so you don't need to do nearly so many iterations of `for line in nodes:` that are largely skipped?

Comment: Try to compute the `abs(v.data[i])` outside of the most inner loop and to set up a temporary variable to not recompute it several time.

Comment: put your code in a function and execute it. That alone will increase your performance greatly with almost no changes.

Comment: @Serdalis: Thanks, I'll do that!

Comment: @robert: Thanks I think it will be much faster

Comment: @njzk2: I believe the idea is simple... the coding is not very nice

Comment: @jpcgandre : I mean as a formal big-O notation. see my answer

Comment: @robert: based on your suggestion I was able to reduce the runtime to 1 min and 30s... great! but I'd like it to be under 30s....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm appears to be:

```
O(nsteps * frames_in_step * values_in_frame * nodes)
```

That sums up to `O(n^4)` if you have no prior knowledge of the size of any element.

As robert pointed out, apparently, you only use one node at each iteration. You could use a `dict` of `nodeID: (x,y,z)`. That would allow a `O(1)` retrieval of the node. Typically a pretreatment would be:

```
nodes_dict = { nodeID:(x,y,z) for nodeID, x, y, z in nodes }
```

Then in the loop, simply call:

```
x, y, z = nodes_dict.get(int(v.nodeLabel))
```

That reduces your complexity to `O(n^3)`. I don't think the algorithm can be further simplified.

Then, you are accessing several times the same array items. This is quite slow, so you can cache them. `v.data[x]` is used 4 to 8 times in each iteration. You can use a temporary variable to reduce that to only 1.

### Edit

As noted in my comment, `umax = max(v.data)` for all indexes of data.
Given `u1max = max(v.values[0]` for all values, `u2max = max(v.values[1]` and `u3max = max(v.values[2]`, it appears that `umax = max(u1max, u2max, u3max)`

Therefore, you can put the `umax` treatment after you process is complete **outside of all the loops**, and simply put this :

```
if abs(u1max) >umax: #maximum UX
    umax=abs(u1max)
    tu='U1'
    stepumax=stepu1max
    nodeumax=nodeu1max
    incumax=incu1max
if abs(u2max) >umax: #maximum UY
    umax=abs(u2max)
    tu='U2'
    stepumax=stepu2max
    nodeumax=nodeu2max
    incumax=incu2max
if abs(u3max) >umax: #maximum UZ
    umax=abs(u3max)
    tu='U3'
    stepumax=stepu3max
    nodeumax=nodeu3max 
    incumax=incu3max
```

Same goes for `uFmax`.

Comment: Also, I just noted : at the end of the process, umax = max(u1max, u2max, u3max). This part can therefore be entirely moved after the loop (same goes for uFmax)

Comment: Thanks! The runtime is now about 1 min!

Answer (score 3):

You say you have 4 steps, 2000 frames, and 10000 nodes. In light of those numbers, here are a few ideas:

**Move calculations outside the node-loop**. If a value does not vary by node, make calculations using the value before you enter the node-loop.

**Think about a different data structure for nodes**. For all 8000 step-frames, you iterate over the entire node list. But you only care about the nodes that satisfy the two conditional tests based on `nodeID`, `x`, and `y`. It might be faster if you could lookup up the needed nodes directly. For example:

```
nodesDict[(nodeID, x, y)] = List of nodes with same NodeID, x, and y.
```

**Pre-process the node data before the step-frame loops**, making all needed conversions (e.g., conversions to integer).

**Refactor for maintainability**. You've got several chunks of code doing essentially the same thing, with slight variations. It's difficult to maintain code like this over the long term, because you've got to notice subtle differences in a **mind-numbing sea of similar syntax**. Think about a different data structure, or consider a way to use iteration to reduce the code duplication. Such changes won't necessarily make your code run faster (and might make it run slightly slower), but the tradeoff is usually worthwhile, because you'll be able to reason about your code more effectively -- and thus discover where the real performance bottlenecks are.

Comment: +1 several generally good/useful ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can at least save yourself some calculations by combining criteria 1 and 2, depending on your  values of umax and u1max

```
if abs(v.data[0]) >uFmax:
    calcs
elif abs(v.data[0] > u1Fmax:
    calcs
```

Are you using :memory: to hold the database?

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that. And no i'm not using memory

Comment: Won't your suggestion skip the `elif` if the `if` is `true`?

Comment: Depends on the ordinality of your evaluations and you want them in descending order -- so if x > 50 then do this first thing, elif x > 5 do this second thing.

if you can use the sqlite and set the connection to :memory: you will see a huge speed boost, even if the underlying drive is SSD.  I'm running 200K complex lookups and calcs in an hour when using a file on SSD, but that same program takes 22 minutes when using :memory:

Comment: I'm using abaqus (http://www.3ds.com/products/simulia/portfolio/abaqus/) output database (*.odb). I'll study sqlite and memmory

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 2, try replacing `range` with `xrange`, as per http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Use_xrange_instead_of_range

This doesn't apply to Python 3. And will only make a difference if looping over huge number of iterations.

Answer (score 1):

If you are pulling this data from a file, build a database or use redis to store a sorted set (key-tuple) of the data.

Then just use a query (or in redis, zrank) to retrieve the maximum -- what you appear to have here is a "find the maximum value in a column" function, whereas a database has all of that code pre-built and optimized for you to enjoy at maximum speed.